# Messenger Bot: Webview form action

Tags: webview, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I have a chatbot and I want to use webview forms when the "survey" is "non-linear"

I have this form. What to "place" in the `action` if I want to tell the bot to catch the data?

```
<form action="I SEARCHING FOR THIS" method="GET">
  <input type="text" name="foo" placeholder="foo" />
  <input type="text" name="bar" placeholder="bar" />
  <button type="submit">SUBMIT</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Action should be sent to the URL for your webhook. Also, if you are sending data you should POST not GET.